# How to merge two parts of an image in Illustrator to avoid overlapping effect shadow

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, merge

First time in this community. I am new to illustrator as I come from a science and research background. I extract this image directly from MATLAB in eps to export it to illustrator and probably because of the way MATLAB treats images, the shape is divided by two as you can see in the image. The colorbar is an automatic object that comes out of a certain programming in the app, is not something I draw. The thing is the colorbar object is cut in half and I would like to merge. I have tried the pathfinder>merge option and it says it does not produce any results.

I would appreciate any help.

Thanks!

[image: Overlapping antialiasing]

[image: Entire image]

UPDATE: This is the same problem but with other type of object I have when I deal with brain activation images from the same app. It automatically segments the object. It looks like it's an image although it saves it in eps. I'd like to know how to tell illustrator it's just an object and to not separate it so it doesn't have to antialias the edges and display the white line showed in the colormap bar (which also happens in the topography object).

[image: Brain activation topography]

Comment: Is the graph an image inside of an EPS file or is the graph a vector? Looks like an image to me. path finder -> merge should work for what you're trying to do if the graph was a vector.

Comment: @andrew is right but the tick marks look like they might be a separate shape component. You might need to *release compound path* first to avoid merge problems and then reorder the layers to put the tick marks back on top.

Comment: I would redraw this in Illustrator. It's a simple gradient, blend for the tick marks, and type.

Comment: Release the clipping mask?

Comment: @AndrewH I guess its an image and this is why this is not working the merge, still the cut of the image comes as I import it to illustrator, I make no modifications from MATLAB output, it seems to import it automatically this way.

Comment: @Rykara it looks like this option is dimmed. Maybe because it might be an image, right?

Comment: @Scott you are right, I also thought this as first option, the problem comes with other type of images, in my case brain topographies, that I also have a cut version of the object after importing it into illustrator fromthe eps output. I was asking with hope there would be some sort of way I could import it in one piece or maybe join paths after or something.

Comment: @joojaa I tried it and the bars dissappeared leaving only what seems to be the intersection part, I believe it is the one that looks like a white line in the attached image. Thanks all for the comments folks, really appreciate them!

Comment: @UnaiVicente yeah it can do that. Sometimes you need to repeat the releasing and delete the clipping paths to see the object. Espeically matlab tends to make really really hard to handle data structures and cleaning is a bit of work. Sometimes it renames a existing font so that it can not be opened for example.

Comment: If you still need help, I think seeing your Layers panel would be helpful.

Comment: Wouldn’t it be a good idea if you upload a sample eps somewhere so someone could inspect it whether it’s vector graphics? Sometimes an outline mode can give you an idea but again unless we have the file it’s difficult to guess.

Comment: Any possibility of saving PDF rather than EPS? EPS is a flat file format with 1 bit transparency. That is typically *why* things get broken up in an EPS. If you could save to a PDF you may find artwork constructed much better when opened in AI.

Comment: @scott has the best suggestion so far. Even the lower graph would be pretty straightforward to recreate as a vector image. The little topographical lines are right in the middle of each color break so one could use them to make a blend.

Comment: Hi, I ended up taking @Scott suggestion and figured it out a way to save the image in pdf and my problems were solved. EPS does not seem the best of the outputs today if you later want to edit the things. Thanks all for your comments, I really appreciate them!

Answer (score -1):

> I'd like to know how to tell illustrator it's just an object

You can link the file by going to File -> Place (Shift+CTRL+P). A new window will open where you can choose the image. Make sure the "Link" checkbox is checked.

Comment: It actually does the same thing once the image is embedded. Thanks anyway.